# Call Java (ImageJ plugin BoneJ) from a Jython script

Tags: java, jython, imagej

**Sorry, I am very new to both python and java so I might not recognize that this has been answered and only needs adjusted for my situation.

Essentially I have a script manager that operates in a python environment and I need to pass data off to the bonej plugin for analysis, which should then return an array that will then be used by another python script for further analysis.

I have been directed to jython as a way to do this, but I can't figure out how to import imageJ as if it were a module.

I know that I can simply open imagej from a command line and direct it to analyze an image, but this is not what I need because it simply returns an average in a segment of bone.

Basically I need to tell imagej that it should analyze this segment of bone, return the array, then this next segment of bone. An additional python script interpolates the arrays onto a predefined background grid.

If anyone has some insight on how to achieve this back and fort from jython I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use Jython to call ImageJ. See the [Jython scripting](http://fiji.sc/Jython_Scripting) page on the Fiji wiki for an overview and lots of example code. One easy way to get started from within ImageJ is to use the [Script Editor](http://fiji.sc/Script_Editor). You can then invoke your Jython scripts from the command line using the ImageJ launcher [[instructions](http://fiji.sc/Headless#Running_scripts_in_headless_mode)]. Or you can run them via the `jython` executable by [adding the needed Java libraries to the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586305/1207769).

But beware: this [does not provide total integration between Python libraries and Java ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10579887/1207769). The problem is that many Python libraries are backed by C code, making them accessible only from CPython, and not from Jython. For example, the very popular SciPy and NumPy libraries cannot be called directly from Jython code.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I am looking into Fiji now. Hopefully this will work out.