# Using Python in NetBeans 8.1

Tags: python, netbeans

I'm trying to add Python functionality to NetBeans 8.1.  I downloaded Python from the Python website [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/).  (I'm using Windows 10, by the way.)  I also downloaded the NetBeans plugins "Python" and "Jython Distribution" (required by the former).  Now I have two questions:

### 1.

When I create a new Python project, I have these options:

[image: New Python Project]

Based on the description for the "Setuptools" choice, I'm guessing that I **shouldn't** use that one since it's not for Windows.  So **am I correct in choosing "Python Project - Ant"?**

### 2.

The Python platform that is selected by default is "Jython 2.7.0," as shown below.

[image: Python Platform Manager]

I'm assuming that what I got from the Python website was a Python platform too, so I'd *like* to use that if possible.  But in trying to add another platform, I don't know what file to choose in my Python folder.  All of the ones I've tried result in the error:

[image: Python Platform Error]

I guess I could use the Jython platform, but I would think that the stuff I downloaded *straight from Python* would be the best.  **Do I need to add and make default the stuff I downloaded?  Or should I ignore that and just use the Jython platform?**

If yes to "should I add a platform", **what file do I select?**

Thanks in advance for any help.

### EDIT:

I was able to create and run successfully a Python project using the "Python Project - Ant" option as mentioned in question **1**, using the Jython platform.  So **question 1 is taken care of.**  I still would like to be able to use the Python platform I downloaded from their website, though, so **question 2 still needs an answer**.

Comment: Have you tried following the [Netbeans Python Tutorial](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansPythonTutorial) to get up and running?

Comment: Yes, I was looking at that before I asked the question.  My issues with it are: 1) They're using a Mac.  I'm on Windows, so I wasn't sure how things would work for me.  2) I still need help finding the "Python Interpreter" (step 2 in _Setting Your Platform Runtime_) among what I downloaded from Python.  See my 2nd problem.  3) The options in _Starting a new project_ are different from mine.  Compare my first screenshot to the one in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are trying to run other python distributions from netbeans, here is what i found:

From python wiki - https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments

> Python/Jython support in NetBeans -- Open source, allows Python and Jython Editing, code-completion, debugger, refactoring, templates, syntax analysis, etc.;
>
> **UPDATE:** Netbeans 7.0 released without Python support. Check
> http://wiki.netbeans.org/Python70Roadmap for upcoming Python support.

So it looks like, python (Cbased) will no longer be suported in NetBeans, only Java-based Jython - also look on this question:

[What is the difference between Python vs Jython vs IronPython vs wxPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579824/what-is-the-difference-between-python-vs-jython-vs-ironpython-vs-wxpython)